# Harry Potter fanfic where Ginny is determined to marry Harry who has no interest in her

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

It's one of those "Ginny is determined to marry Harry who has no interest in her" stories. The Weasley family encounters him in the lobby or on the front steps of Gringotts one day (the shopping for school supplies trip, maybe) and Ginny announces, publicly for all bystanders to hear, that she is carrying Harry's child. BTW, Ginny is well aware that Harry is not the father.  He denies it, and insists on having a test done immediately in Gringotts. The test shows Harry is not the father.

The test required each of the supposed parents to put their finger in a slot on opposite sides of a small box.  A small blood sample was taken from each person and the results (yes this IS the father, or no, not a match), are produced quickly.  I don't think it can identify who is the actual father, if it is not the person being tested.

Skip forward in time a little bit. Back in session at Hogwarts, Harry is called to Dumbledore's office and told he needs to do the responsible thing and marry Ginny. He again protests that it isn't his kid. The Weasleys and Dumbledore tell him they will have Poppy verify the paternity. Harry protests there is no need, as the goblins did that already. He is told the Gringotts test is not reliable, but Poppy can tell them 100% for sure. Harry is suspicious that Poppy's results will be rigged, and points out that all the Purebloods who rely on the Gringotts tests to certify their bloodlines would be shocked to hear Dumbledore considers the Gringotts test to be unreliable.

I don't remember where it went from there, but I think this was just one episode in a fairly long fic. I mainly read Snarry or Harmony fics, so if there is a ship, it is likely one of those. I tend to dislike Ginny, so this could easily be part of a Ginny-bashing fic.  I read mostly on AO3 and FFN, so it is likely archived on one of those.

Comment: I'm not even halfway through but I have to ask, when did Gringotts _bank_ start to handle paternity tests?! Maybe it was St Mungo's instead?

Comment: Hey, it's fanfic!  I don't think logic is a trait that fanfic writers value highly.  I suspect the reasoning is that since many stories have the bank doing "inheritance tests" that basically show the family tree of the person tested, that this wouldn't be that big a stretch.  To a society obsessed with purity of bloodlines, knowing for sure that your wife is pregnant with YOUR child would probably be quite significant.

Comment: When did you read this? (so I can discard newer fanfics when searching)

Comment: Not positive, but I think about 6 months ago--not that that is any guarantee that the story isn't much older than that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I accidentally found it myself.  Wasn't looking for it, but the scene with the pregnancy test at the bank showed up about 2/3 of the way through "The Ripple Effect" by Immortality22.  https://archiveofourown.org/works/10063583

Thanks to everyone who tried to assist me.

Comment: When you return, don't forget you can accept your own answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Harry Potter and the Pureblood Supremacist](http://Harry%20Potter%20and%20the%20Pureblood%20Supremacist)

> Harry's life is turned upside down after receiving a letter from
> Sirius. Starts after OOTP. Contains Manipulative Dumbledore, Ron and
> Ginny Bashing. H/Hr

Excerpt from [chapter 13](https://m.fanfiction.net/s/5167776/13/Harry-Potter-and-the-Pureblood-Supremacist):

> Kontor stepped into the center of the room and the door closed with a
> bang. "Please step onto the indicated circles. Mr. Potter you will be
> on the right and Ms. Weasley you will on the left." After following
> these directions, Kontor started to chant in a different language so
> Harry had no idea what he was talking about. After listening to the
> chanting for 5 minutes Kontor motioned for Harry to step forward and
> hold out his arm. Harry did this and was cut with a goblin knife. His
> wound healed right away. Ginny next stepped forward and had her arm
> cut. After mixing the two blood samples in one bowl a flash of light
> appeared and then a piece of parchment. Kontor then clapped his hands
> and the doors opened again and he led them outside.
>
> "After performing the ritual it has been discovered that the child being held in Ms. Weasley's womb is not Mr. Potters."

Comment: While this story does have the goblins providing a paternity test, I don't think it is the one I'm looking for.  In this one, once the goblins say Harry isn't the father, Ginny caves and tells everyone who the father really is.  I'm pretty sure that the in the story I'm looking for, she (and her mother and Dumbledore) try to say the goblins' test is wrong, and insist Harry IS the father.